# Adding an click event to a programatically added menu item

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, menuitem

I am working on a C# WPF project and I am storing some items in an SQLite database, when the program loads, it then retrieves the items from the database and adds the items to the menu. What I then need to do is to allow the user to click on one of the added menu items and something is done based on what was clicked. I can't find anything on how to do this, below is the code for how I am adding the menu item to the menu programatically.

```
StoredDBConnectionManager storedDbConnectionManager = new StoredDBConnectionManager(Properties.Settings.Default.app_dbPassword);
List<string> connections = storedDbConnectionManager.getStoredConnections();

foreach (string connection in connections)
{
      mnuFileDBConnections.Items.Add(connection);
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example:

XAML:

```
<Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
```

Code behind:

```
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();

    MenuItem item = new MenuItem { Header = "test" };
    item.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(item_Click);
    menu1.Items.Add(item);
}

public void item_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: My click is not being called.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `MenuItem` control you can instantiate and use the `connection` as its `Header` or `Content`.

`MenuItem` will then have a `Click` event handler against it or you can set the command.

Ideally however, you should be retrieving the `connections` collection, setting it to a property on your `model` and then have the `menu` bound to that collection, that way it's a simple matter of making use of an `ItemTemplate` for the menu.

e.g.

```
        StoredDBConnectionManager storedDbConnectionManager = new StoredDBConnectionManager(Properties.Settings.Default.app_dbPassword);
        List<string> connections = storedDbConnectionManager.getStoredConnections();

        foreach (string connection in connections)
        {
            var mi = new MenuItem()
            {
                Header = connection,
            };

            mi.Click += ConnectionMenuItemClicked;

            mnuFileDBConnections.Items.Add(mi);
        }
```

OR with binding:

```
    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}">
        <Menu.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding}" Click="ConnectionsMenuItem_Clicked">

                </MenuItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemTemplate>
    </Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(string menuCaption from ...)
{
    MenuItem mi=new MenuItem();
    mi.Header = meniCaption;
    mi.Click += (s,e) =>
        {
             ...
        }
}
```